# Sending SIGUSR1 to parent

Tags: bash, kill, ipc

When I do a `kill -SIGUSR1 $PPID` I get `kill: (1) - Operation not permitted` . How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My parent process had died for some reason. This caused the issue. I took care of that and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permissions to send this signal. If you have `sudo` rights, do `sudo kill -SIGUSR1 $PPID`

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I am able to send SIGUSR1 from a sub-shell and the default disposition is taken.

Comment: if you do `ps aux | grep $PPID` you should see as which user that process is running. If you are not root, and this proc is running as another user than yourself, then you will most likely have no permissions to send signals to it.

Comment: could you please post the output of `whoami` and `ps aux | grep $PPID`?

Comment: `vysakhp  18563  0.0  0.0  90820  1772 ?        S    08:50   0:00 sshd: vysakhp@pts/1

-bash-3.2$ whoami
vysakhp
`